# converting String to Json - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

Hi I'm trying to convert a string like this:

```
{'2': [1], '0': [1]}
```

to json using JSON.parse in javascript but it keeps saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

can anyone help me with this, thanks

Comment: Because that's not JSON.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: JSON does not accept simple quotes as string delimiters, use double quotes instead

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to convert a string to an object? Because that's what `JSON.parse` does: It converts JSON **to** a JavaScript value. It does *not* convert *to* JSON, that's what `JSON.stringify` does. JSON is a language-independent, textual data exchange format, it's not a JavaScript value / data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it with curly braces to make it work. ex. This will work fine.

```
"{"0":[1],"2":[1]}"
```